# How can I get query masonry to change to 1 column width for my website?

Tags: jquery, media, mobile-website

My website uses masonry to change sizes, and it works when I change my computer browser's window size, but when I look at my site on my iPhone it shows 3 columns, and I would like it to change to one column to fill my iPhones screen.  How can I set this up?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here is my website...it is built in wordpress

www.chrisbalzanodesign.com/wordpress

Comment: is this only an iPhone problem or wouldn't this problem apply to all mobile browsers (Android, Crackberry, etc.)?

Comment: I assume it would be all mobile browsers, I have only tried it on my iPhone.